# RedShift: Alternative to 'where in' to compare annual login activity

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here are the two cases:

**Members Lost**: Get the distinct count of user ids from 365 days ago who haven't had any activity since then

**Members Added**: Get the distinct count of user ids from today who don't exist in the previous 365 days.

Here are the SQL statements I've been writing. Logically I feel like this should work (and it does for sample data), but the dataset is 5Million+ rows and takes forever! Is there any way to do this more efficiently? (base_date is a calendar that I'm joining on to build out a 2 year trend. I figured this was faster than joining the 5million table on itself...)

```
-- Members Lost
SELECT
    effective_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT dwuserid) as members_lost
FROM base_date
LEFT JOIN site_visit 

    -- Get Login Activity for 365th day
    ON DATEDIFF(day, srclogindate, effective_date) = 365

WHERE dwuserid NOT IN (

    -- Get Distinct Login activity for Current Day (PY) + 1 to Current Day (CY) (i.e. 2013-01-02 to 2014-01-01)
    SELECT DISTINCT dwuserid 
    FROM site_visit b 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, b.srclogindate, effective_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 364

)
GROUP BY effective_date
ORDER BY effective_date;

-- Members Added
SELECT
    effective_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT dwuserid) as members_added
FROM base_date

LEFT JOIN site_visit ON srclogindate = effective_date

WHERE dwuserid NOT IN (

    SELECT DISTINCT dwuserid 
    FROM site_visit b
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, b.srclogindate, effective_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 365

)
GROUP BY effective_date
ORDER BY effective_date;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @JohnR for pointing me in the right direction. I had to tweak your response a bit because I need to know on any login day how many were "Member Added" or "Member Lost" so it had to be a 365 rolling window looking back or looking forward. Finding the IDs that didn't have a match in the LEFT JOIN was much faster.

```
-- Trim data down to one user login per day
CREATE TABLE base_login AS
SELECT DISTINCT "dwuserid", "srclogindate"
FROM site_visit

-- Members Lost
SELECT
    current."srclogindate",
    COUNT(DISTINCT current."dwuserid") as "members_lost"
FROM base_login current
LEFT JOIN base_login future 
    ON current."dwuserid" = future."dwuserid" 
    AND current."srclogindate" < future."srclogindate" 
    AND DATEADD(day, 365, current."srclogindate") >= future."srclogindate"
WHERE future."dwuserid" IS NULL 
GROUP BY current."srclogindate"

-- Members Added
SELECT
    current."srclogindate",
    COUNT(DISTINCT current."dwuserid") as "members_added"
FROM base_login current
LEFT JOIN base_login past
    ON current."dwuserid" = past."dwuserid" 
    AND current."srclogindate" > past."srclogindate" 
    AND DATEADD(day, 365, past."srclogindate") >= current."srclogindate"    
WHERE past."dwuserid" IS NULL 
GROUP BY current."srclogindate"
```

Comment: You appear to have confused `IN` and `EXISTS`.

Comment: doh, good catch. So many different iterations of trial and error and I messed up my saved query. Though the question remains because WHERE IN is taking forever. I've updated the query to what was running against the full data. Thanks

Comment: the old query was running a Where Not Exists but the Where clause on the sub query did WHERE DATEDIFF AND d.dwuserid = dwuserid

Comment: NOT IN should generally be avoided because it has to scan all data. Instead of joining to the site_visit table (which is presumably huge), try joining to a sub-query that selects UserID and the most recent login date -- that way, there is only one row per user instead of one row per visit. eg: select userid, max(srclogindate) group by userid

Comment: OK, I think I got a solution that is running much faster now. @JohnR if you put your comment in as an answer I'll give you credit for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN` should generally be avoided because it has to scan all data.

Instead of joining to the site_visit table (which is presumably huge), try joining to a sub-query that selects UserID and the most recent login date -- that way, there is only one row per user instead of one row per visit.

For example:

```
SELECT dwuserid, min (srclogindate) as first_login, max(srclogindate) as last_login
FROM site_visit
GROUP BY dwuserid
```

You could then simplify the queries to something like:

```
-- Members Lost: Last login was between 12 and 13 months ago
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT dwuserid, min(srclogindate) as first_login, max(srclogindate) as last_login
    FROM site_visit
    GROUP BY dwuserid
    )
WHERE
    last_login BETWEEN current_date - interval '13 months' and current_date - interval '12 months'

-- Members Added: First visit in last 12 months
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT dwuserid, min(srclogindate) as first_login, max(srclogindate) as last_login
    FROM site_visit
    GROUP BY dwuserid
    )
WHERE
    first_login > current_date - interval '12 months'
```

Comment: thanks, see my update on the final solution I used. You got me thinking about this differently.